# I'm having trouble applying the square root function to an equation comprised of float (C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I'm getting an error (CS0117) 'Math' does not contain a definition for 'sqrt'

I'm trying to calculate the answer to an equation and therefore need to square root a combination of variables and display the answer

```
            case 4:

                P1 = float.Parse(TextP1.Text);
                Vol1 = float.Parse(TextVol1.Text);
                U1 = float.Parse(TextU1.Text);
                Vel1 = float.Parse(TextVel1.Text);
                h1 = float.Parse(TextH1.Text);
                Q = float.Parse(TextQ.Text);
                P2 = float.Parse(TextP2.Text);
                Vol2 = float.Parse(TextVol2.Text);
                U2 = float.Parse(TextU2.Text);
                Vel2 = float.Parse(TextVel2.Text);
                h2 = float.Parse(TextH2.Text);
                W = float.Parse(TextW.Text);

                Vel1 = Math.sqrt(((P2 * Vol2) + U2 + ((Vel2 * Vel2) / 2) + (g * h2) + W - Q - (g * h1) - U1 - (P1 * Vol1)) / 2);
                TextU1.Text = U1.ToString();

                break;
```

Comment: `Math.Sqrt` instead of `Math.sqrt` c# is case sensitive.

Comment: Awesome, can't believe I missed that, it's saying it can't convert double to float, is the easiest solution to just change everything to double?

Comment: Change everything to `double`. Use `TryParse` instead of `Parse`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C# is case sensitive. Try `Math.Sqrt` instead of `Math.sqrt`.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.sqrt(v=vs.110).aspx